# React/Jest: Simulate users tampering with the HTML

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

In a React vanilla form, I need to solve an issue where users edit manually the value of an option to make the form submit bad values.

To reproduce, the users inspect the element, and manually change the `value` of an `option` to an invalid value (domain-wise).

The fix is easy, but I want to create a failing unit test before fixing, in a TDD fashion, and cannot figure how to model this in a test. I use jest and react-testing-library.

Here is the form code:

```js
export const CreateTripForm = ({ countries, onSubmit }) => {
    const [countryId, setCountryId] = useState()

    const submit = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        if (countryId === undefined) return 

        await onSubmit(countryId)
    }

    return (
        <form onSubmit={submit}>
            <legend>Choose a country</legend>
            
            <label htmlFor="countryId">Country</label>
            <select name="countryId" required value={countryId} onChange={(e) => setCountryId(e.target.value)}>
                <option value=""></option>
                {countries.map((country) =>
                    <option key={country.id} value={country.id}>{country.label}</option>
                )}
            </select>

            <input type="submit" value="Create a trip" />
        </form>
    )
}
```

Here is what I tried to do, but the test passes instead of failing:

```js
it('keeps previous countryId if the selected one has been tampered with', () => {
    const onSubmit = jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve())

    const countries = [
        { id: 'fr', label: 'France' },
        { id: 'en', label: 'England' },
    ]

    const { container } = render(
        <CreateTripForm countries={countries} onSubmit={onSubmit} />
    )

    const select = container.querySelector('select[name=countryId]')
    const submitButton = container.querySelector('input[type=select]')

    // Select the 'fr' option, it works.
    fireEvent.change(select, { target: { value: 'fr' } })

    submitButton.click()
    expect(onSubmit).toHaveBeenCalledWith('fr')

    // Edit an option to have an incorrect value, it should keep the previous value.
    elements.unitSelect.options[2].value = 'asgard'
    fireEvent.change(select, { target: { value: 'asgard' } })

    submitButton.click()
    expect(onSubmit).toHaveBeenCalledWith('fr')
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had some bad experiences with `expect()` like this before.
Have you tried to separate the tests? One for success and one for failure?
From what I can see, the first `expect()` doesn't reset what he have been called already so I guess that's why your test have passed on the second `expect()`.
Try it like this:

```
it('keeps previous countryId if the selected one has been tampered with', () => {
    const onSubmit = jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve())

    const countries = [
        { id: 'fr', label: 'France' },
        { id: 'en', label: 'England' },
    ]

    const { container } = render(
        <CreateTripForm countries={countries} onSubmit={onSubmit} />
    )

    const select = container.querySelector('select[name=countryId]')
    const submitButton = container.querySelector('input[type=select]')

    // Select the 'fr' option, it works.
    fireEvent.change(select, { target: { value: 'fr' } })

    submitButton.click()
    expect(onSubmit).toHaveBeenCalledWith('fr')
})

it('should prevent sending with tampered select', () => {
    const onSubmit = jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve())
    const countries = [
        { id: 'fr', label: 'France' },
        { id: 'en', label: 'England' },
    ]
    const { container } = render(
        <CreateTripForm countries={countries} onSubmit={onSubmit} />
    )
    const select = container.querySelector('select[name=countryId]')
    const submitButton = container.querySelector('input[type=select]')
    elements.unitSelect.options[2].value = 'asgard'
    fireEvent.change(select, { target: { value: 'asgard' } })

    submitButton.click()
    expect(onSubmit).not.toHaveBeenCalled()
})
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
I get it, but what I want is not preventing the submit when tampered with, but keeping the previous value, that's why I had both `expect`s in the same test.

Comment: But you don’t keep the previous value. Once you trigger the select change to “asgard”, the onChange callback is called and it sets countryId to “asgard”. I am a bit confused with what you want to test, could you clarify it a bit more?